# Can I obtain an International Drivers license whilst abroad?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, greek-citizens

I am currently in the U.S and I won't be able to leave the country soon and I really need to drive. I am an exchange visitor and I've been here for 2 years. I do have a Colorado license but it will expire in mid June and I won't be able to renew it because my J1 visa will expire as well. I will be married by that time but I can't wait To get my temporary green card to start driving again. That might take months. I do have a Greek license which expires in 2055 and it has my name and last name in Latin and the dates (birth, expiration) are easy to understand, but the rest is in Greek, that's why I'm asking if I can just translate that somewhere in the U.S. Will I be able to translate my a Greek drivers license somewhere in the U.S or get an international drivers license without going back to Greece?

Comment: How long have you been there? are you an immigrant or just a visitor?

Comment: on what do you base your theory that you can't renew you Colorado license because of the state of your J1 visa?

Comment: I've been told that I can't get a license while waiting for the green card. I'm gonna have proof of residence but can't do much.

Comment: I am an exchange visitor and I've been here for 2 years. I do have a colorado license but it will expire in mid June and I won't be able to renew it because my J1 visa will expire as well. I will be married by that time but I can't wait To get my temporary green card to start driving again. That might take months. I do have a Greek license which expires in 2055 and it has my name and last name in Latin and the dates (birth, expiration) are easy to understand, but the rest is in Greek, that's why I'm asking if I can just translate that somewhere in the U.S.

Comment: @Mar: In Colorado since August 2014 you can get driver's licenses that don't require legal presence documents.

Comment: @KateGregory: For the with-legal-presence-document type of driver's license, Colorado apparently does require an unexpired visa: https://www.colorado.gov/pacific/sites/default/files/DR2300B.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is Yes, your license is valid in the USA for a tourist visit, because both Greece and the USA are signatories to the 1949 [Convention on Road Traffic](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Geneva_Convention_on_Road_Traffic). The longer answer is that if the license is entirely in Greek, it will probably not be accepted when you need it: at a rental car office, or talking to a policeman. If there is an English translation on the license, you should be good to go. If there is a Latin-alphabet version but the translation is in another language (e.g., French), your success will be in between.

You will not be able to get an International Drivers Permit if already in the USA.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of Greece, but to get an international license, all you need is your license & 2 passport size photo. I guess you can get it made if you can courier it to Greece.
But I do not know if its illegal or will they issue the license without seeing the applicant in person.

Answer (score -1):

Each state has its own driving laws. This official website gives an overview:
http://www.usa.gov/Topics/Foreign-Visitors-Driving.shtml

It also provides a link to this page that will let you check the law in any of the 50 states:
http://www.usa.gov/Topics/Motor-Vehicles.shtml

It also says, "The residency requirement for obtaining a U.S. driver's license is different in each state. Check the department of motor vehicles in the state where you live to see the requirements" and links to the page above.

It also says, "Once you receive your U.S. driver's license from a state motor vehicle department, you can drive in all U.S. states."